# Google's own reference example doesn't even work? Writing custom signed urls for GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

I've followed there instruction as shown in this reference, however I am getting a "Signature does not match error" and I don't know why.

```
Coincidentally, Google's reference example for this 
https://storage.googleapis.com/example-bucket/cat.jpeg?X-Goog-Algorithm=
GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=example%40example-project.iam.gserviceaccount
.com%2F20181026%2Fus-central-1%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20181026T18
1309Z&X-Goog-Expires=900&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=247a2aa45f16
9edf4d187d54e7cc46e4731b1e6273242c4f4c39a1d2507a0e58706e25e3a85a7dbb891d62afa849
6def8e260c1db863d9ace85ff0a184b894b117fe46d1225c82f2aa19efd52cf21d3e2022b3b868dc
c1aca2741951ed5bf3bb25a34f5e9316a2841e8ff4c530b22ceaa1c5ce09c7cbb5732631510c2058
0e61723f5594de3aea497f195456a2ff2bdd0d13bad47289d8611b6f9cfeef0c46c91a455b94e90a
66924f722292d21e24d31dcfb38ce0c0f353ffa5a9756fc2a9f2b40bc2113206a81e324fc4fd6823
a29163fa845c8ae7eca1fcf6e5bb48b3200983c56c5ca81fffb151cca7402beddfc4a76b13344703
2ea7abedc098d2eb14a7
```

also gives a signature does not match error.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: The example signed URL is from 2018 and set to expire in 900 seconds. It is not intended as a functioning URL.  Can you say which example did you use?  Can you provide some of the steps you took?

Comment: Yeah I understand the link expires, but if it was just a problem with expiration it would say link is expired. I don't think they should be providing examples which return errors about the signature. I've essentially copied their python code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-python) regarding this topic. In there you will have some Python examples for creating Signed URLs to download and object or upload it.

For example if using a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), you will be able to specify the amount of time your url is valid before it expires:

```
url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
        # Allow GET requests using this URL.
        method="GET",
    )
```